# Open Atrium 2: Get back the old design

Tags: 7, distributions

Is there a way to make Open Atrium 2 look a bit more like Open Atrium 1 (e.g. display icons for the sections)?
We'd like to make it easier for our users to switch. Besides OA 1 looks friendlier in our opinion.